# Is it possible synchronise inbox messages using User.messages.list?

Tags: gmail-api

I am working on an application that requires checking the user's inbox for new messages every 5mins.

The current approach we've taken is to utilise the list.histories endpoint based on push notifications. We're running into the edge case where we get stale history IDs for accounts that go cold for a few weeks. I understand the remedy in this situation is to do a full sync using the list messages.

I was wondering if it was possible to just use list.messages to poll the list of messages every 5-10 mins using the list.messages endpoint with q filters to restrict the timeframe. The implementation would be something involving querying with overlapping timeframes of 1 min; The idea is that having that overlap would allow us figure out where we've left off and then stitch the sequence correctly. We will not be using pub/sub or list.histories any more.

The concerns i have are:

1. This approach isn't listed in guide.
2. Is it possible for a message with a history_id that is greater than the message that precedes it to have an internal date that is older?

Does anyone else have experience with this?

Comment: Any reason why you are polling and not just using https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push.  Polling is not scaleable and is probably gong to eat your quota.

Comment: We deal with accounts that sometimes go dormant for long periods of time where syncing with the history id isn’t possible anymore. I was hoping to be able to tackle the edge cases in an identical manner.